# German equivalent of the phrase "That reminds me"?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

Is there a German equivalent of the phrase "That reminds me"?

An example usage in English (taken from [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/that-reminds-me)): *That reminds me. I must take the chicken out of the freezer.*

Does perhaps "Das erinnert mich" sound like a plausible German version of the above mentioned English phrase?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Das erinnert mich.* does not sound plausible at all, but feels rather incomplete.
When reading that, I want to ask ***Woran** erinnert es dich?*

Possible phrases are

- Da fällt mir ein, ...
- Wo wir gerade dabei sind, ...
- Wo ich gerade darüber nachdenke, ...

Comment: isn't `Wo wir gerade dabei sind, ...` more like `by the way`?

Comment: ``Das erinnert mich daran, dass ich noch das Hühnchen aus dem Gefrierschrank holen muss`` that's the way i'd say it.

Comment: *Da fällt mir ein* is perfect. However, the other two depend a lot on the situation: *While we're at it* is clearly different; *Speaking/Thinking of this* can be synonymous, but not necessarily.

Comment: My first thought had also been *Wo mir gerade einfällt...* *einfallen* (come to mind) seems to best convey the intent.

Comment: I don't agree: _Das erinnert mich [daran]_ is not incomplete but just the way it would be said. All three examples of possible phrases wouldn't be really used in spoken German.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can translate the phrase "That reminds me of ..." with "Das erinnert mich an ..." However "Das erinnert mich." alone is wrong. In your example you would say:

> Mir fällt gerade ein, dass ich noch...

or:

> Mir fällt gerade etwas ein. Ich muss noch...

Comment: "Da fällt mir was ein...", sagte der Statiker.

Answer (score 6):

Direct translation:

> Das erinnert mich an etwas. Ich muss ja noch das Huhn aus dem Gefrierschrank nehmen.

Many shorten it and say *was* instead of *etwas*, which makes it a tad informal.

We might even say

> Das erinnert mich woran. Ich muss ja noch …

This is quite popular among young people, but it isn't strictly grammatical German (*woran* is usually used only in questions). Nevertheless, [Google does find almost 400 uses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22das%20erinnert%20mich%20woran%22&nfpr=1&rct=j) of this (compared to [18400](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22das%20erinnert%20mich%20woran%22&nfpr=1&rct=j#q=%22das+erinnert+mich+an+was%22) for the *an was* version).

A very brief and informal version:

> Ach ja, ich muss ja noch …

Comment: That is the direct translation, even though I am more likely to say `Mir fällt grad' ein, dass ich (noch) ...`

Answer (score 5):

The expression *apropos* is often used exactly that way.

Comment: It's close, but apropos rather means "speaking of ...".

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the English to German translation of "That reminds me.." usually won't do, if grammatically and stylistically correct German is your goal. 
   That said, most people would probably get what you're trying to say if you used it that way.

The correct translation/phrase in this context would probably be:
"Ach ja! Wo wir grade davon sprechen: (...)"
 or
"Wo wir grad dabei sind - (...)"

If it actually **is** used in the context that something reminds you of an event, some story, or thing in the past, then you would say something like: "Dabei muss ich immer daran denken, wie (...)"

This is only used when something actually reminds you of someone or an occurrance in the past. It is **not** used for e.g.: "That reminds me-I have to pick up the kids from school"  ;)

Answer (score 2):

See 
http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-german/that+reminds+me!

"Das bringt mich auf die Idee ..." sounds quite nice to me.